# Litle question about ufw command

Tags: command-line, ufw

Hi guys i would like to setup a specific rule for my ufw but i have the problem.

How could i type this ?

from ip adress 192.168.1.203 on interface eth0 alow port 80

I have on local pc ip address 192.168.1.203
ubuntu have 2 nics 1 is eth0 lokal network, eth1 wan.
Ubuntu have installed apache service

I would like only my pc to access ubuntu on interface eth0 i that i only have access to open web pages from apache on port 80

i hope you understand me guys :)

Comment: Take a look at [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW).

Comment: yes my friend i read that over and over but there is 
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.4 to any port 22 
but i wont to add and on eth0 to work only





something like this


ufw allow from 192.168.1.203 to tcp port 80 on eth0

Answer (score 0):

this command works good:

```
ufw allow from 192.168.1.203 to 192.168.1.50 port 80 proto tcp
```

203 local machine, 50 apache

but i am finding the way for command to replace 192.168.1.50 with eth0 
so when i change ip adress on that nic eth0 to rule stay....

Answer (score 0):

> By default, ufw will apply rules to all available interfaces. To  limit
>          this,  specify  DIRECTION on INTERFACE, where DIRECTION is one of in or
>          out (interface aliases are not supported).  For example, to  allow  all
>          new incoming http connections on eth0, use:
>
> ufw allow in on eth0 to any port 80 proto tcp

from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/ufw.8.html

So

```
sudo ufw allow in on eth0 from 192.168.1.203 to 192.168.1.50 port 80 proto tcp
```

You can specify a netmask if you wish, example

> ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/16